# How do you print selected values from a list using a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have just started learning the basics of Python at college and during a task I have been assigned I was asked to write code to print the first 3 values in my list using a while loop. My list contains 5 values which are all strings.

Since I am new to Python and this is my first task using lists I messed around with the code a lot, editing it to see if it would make a difference (which it didn't apart from creating errors or printing half of the desired output).

One thing I tried was this:

```
while shopping_list == [0:4]
  print (shopping_list[0:3]
```

This just created an infinite loop of printing the first 3 values.

So for now I left it like this:

```
print (shopping_list[0:3])
```

but it needs to be in a while loop

Comment: If you are learning at college, I'm sure you have class notes or textbooks to refer to. If not the internet is flooded with tutorials to learn the basics anyway.

Comment: `shopping_list == [0:4]` is an expression that causes a syntax error, it never ran unlike you suggested. What you're trying to do is following the pattern of a `for` loop - consider how a `while` works. It keeps running while a certain condition is `True`. So, what condition would you need to be `True` until you're done running?

Comment: @Grismar This just shows how new I am to python. As I mentioned I did change the code to something else so it's not written down in front of me right now and because I am so new to python I made a mistake whilst trying to remeber off the top of my head what I had previously written. It may have only been a single "=". Thanks for the feedback on while loops.

Comment: @Julien Yes we breifly went over the basics of while loops and lists in a class but we didn't discuss how to print certain values from a list only either all of them or one of them. Also I am aware that the internet is usful in that way and that is why I have came here after my lecturer pointed me in the direction of this site to look for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `while` loop solution, you could do it with something like:

```py
use_len = min(3, len(shopping_list)) # In case list has less than three.
idx = 0                              # Starting index.
while idx < use_len:                 # For up to three indexes:
    print(shopping_list[idx])        #   Print item at that index.
    idx += 1                         #   Move to next index.
```

This limits the number of loops up front if the shopping list is shorter than three items. Alternatively, you could check for *each* item to see if it exists in the list:

```py
idx = 0                              # Starting index.
while idx < 3:                       # For exactly three indexes:
    if idx < len(shopping_list):     #   If that index exists:
        print(shopping_list[idx])    #     Print it.
    idx += 1                         #   Regardless, move to next index.
```

Another possibility would be to make a copy of the (up to) first three elements and then print each one, removing it afterwards. That would be something like:

```py
short_list = shopping_list[:3]   # Max of three in new list.
while len(short_list) > 0:       # While list not empty:
    print(short_list[0])         #   Print first in list.
    short_list = short_list[1:]  #   Then remove it.
```

That's not the most efficient code but it *does* work.

---

*None* of those are how I would choose to do this task if there wasn't a requirement for `while` loop, since Python provides much more expressive ways. But, if you *have* to use `while`, they're probably the easiest ways.

In terms of those more expressive ways (not using `while` as required, so really just provided as extra information here), I would probably opt for something like:

```py
for item in shopping_list[:3]:
    print(item)
```

Or, once you learn the darker corners of Python:

```py
print("\n".join(shopping_list[:3]))
```

That last one's not a serious suggestion, by the way, though it *does* work, assuming your shopping list consists of string values. But who nowadays goes shopping for things like `42` or `1.414`? :-)

Comment: thanks for your help it is very much appreciated. Honestly don't understand any of that code you have provided but it works perfectly. Also I will message my lecturer and see if he changes his mind about using a while loop for this because I agree that it isn't the best way to do this task.

Comment: With assignments like these, the purpose is not to learn about "the best way to do this task", but rather to learn "how a key construct of the language works" - if you "don't understand any of the code [that was] provided", you have no benefit from this exercise and by missing key parts of learning how to program at the start, you will be at a loss further down the line. Try to fully understand the first example @paxdiablo posted, or you'll have serious trouble in future classes.

Comment: @stobbartaidan: there's a reason why the "best way" was simply added as an addendum rather than making the real answer. It's because you should follow the specifications given to you in the assignment. If educator told you to use `while`, you should do that, since there's almost certainly a good reason for it (such as they're trying to teach you to code in general rather than in Python).

Comment: Also see comment by @Grismar. In light of understanding first code block (as they suggest), I've added comments to it which will hopefully help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I apprecaite the added comments on the code to help me understand it better, it does help. I just don't think that my lecturer intended for me to complete the task in that way because he has never discussed anything about indexes, and usually he sets tasks based on what he has showed us in classes. But I'm sure that I will be able to discuss the way he would have wanted the task to be completed when I have submitted the assignment though.